# Directly extracting PDF from Kile under MiKTeX in Windows 10?

Tags: pdf, editors, kile

I am using the latest testing version of Kile under MiKTeX in Windows 10, which is awesome so far. It took me a while to find how to generate a PDF file, the built-in command seems clicking the "QuickBuild" in the second upper command bar.

However, I still did not find how to extract a PDF directly such that I will have generated PDF document for me to choose where to save it. In contrast, the "QuickBuild" only generates PDF in the file where the source file locates.

Comment: you can't "save" the source file as a pdf as you would e.g. save a word as a pdf. You need to compile it, and this is done in this folder. If you want to move the resulting pdf copy&paste it with the windows explorer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. Hi. That is not what I am asking. For example, in Texstudio or Overleaf one can extract a PDF file independently. My question is about how do I obtain a PDF directly without having to open the source file location file and copy-paste.

Comment: No, they probably simply have some in-built too which allows you to copy the pdf somewhere else.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I am not sure about the meaning of your current reply. But I am looking for a command to do the same action as one can do in Textstudio.

Comment: Please take a moment to read up how TeX compilation works, especially regarding the generated PDF and its location. Basically, a build will create a PDF from the source which is in the folder of the source file. Please note, that if you use TeXStudio's "Save As" and select "PDF file" it will actually save a text file with PDF extension which is not even a valid PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kile for Windows the save PDF command is on the File menu options as

> Save Compiled Document

and by default does not have a shortcut, but you can add one using the Settings > Configure shortcuts - Kile (not the initial Kate Part which is mainly TeX) simply type save in the search box and it should be 5th or 6th option.

if settings is not visible try Alt+S then h for s**h**ortcuts